# AWS ec2 instance is not responding on Public IP

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a simple `index.html` file running on `nginx` webserver,  `port 80` on aws ubuntu instance. I'm able to access the server through tunnel but, when i'm trying to connect using `Public IP`, it shows connection `timed out`.
I've tried many times creating a new instance from scratch but, it didn't work. Any help will be very thankful and if possible please try to keep it simple as i'm just a beginner in the case of webserver.

I fixed this by [Amazon ec2 not working when accessing..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818456/amazon-ec2-not-working-when-accessing-through-public-ip)

Comment: Do your instance's security groups permit traffic to port 80?

Answer (score 2):

Check following settings are done or not :
1. Check if your VPC is having internet gateway attached
2. Check if network access control list is allowing inbound and outbound http traffic
3. Check if security group is allowing 80 traffic

Comment: it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

The tunnel part makes it seem like the instance is on a private subnet but you attached a public IP. The public IPs need to be routes out the internet gateway. So they need to be in a public subnet.

If that is the case then you can add a ELB in a public subnet to front the instance with.

Comment: This one didn't work for me but by adding a network interface did.. Thanks for your reply Mike..

Answer (score 0):

Check the following things...!

1. If you are inside VPC, **Check your igw** whether it is associated to your subnet.
2. Whether your **VPC  Subnet security group** allowing traffic over the internet on port 80 for all the subnets.
3. Also the **subnet of your server,** Is it allowing traffic over the internet on port 80 for all the subnets.